# Can't post a file to a service successfully

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to upload a file through Angularjs. I am hitting the service but not able to get the file on the server. I have posted my code below. Please let me know the errors/modifications in the code.

```
<html>

 <head>
    <script src =  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app = "myApp">

   <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
     <form name="demo">
        <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
        <button type="submit" ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
     </form>
  </div>

  <script>
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

     myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
           restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
              var modelSetter = model.assign;

              element.bind('change', function(){
                 scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                 });
              });
           }
        };
     }]);

     myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
           var fd = new FormData();
           fd.append('file', file);

           $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
              transformRequest: angular.identity,
              headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
           })

           .success(function(){
              console.log('file uploaded');
           })

           .error(function(){
              console.log('file not uploaded');
           });
        }
     }]);

     myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
        $scope.uploadFile = function(){
           var file = $scope.myFile;

           console.log('file is ' );
           console.dir(file);

           var uploadUrl = "http://172.29.5.86:8080/marketplace/inventory/testImageUpload.service";
           fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
        };
     }]);

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you to use https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow.

**HTML**

```
<div flow-init
     flow-name="flowObject.flow"         <!-- optional -->
     flow-file-added="fileAdded($file)"> <!-- optional -->

     <!-- Your HTML -->
     <span class="btn btn-default" data-flow-btn>Select Files</span>
     <span class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="uploadFiles()">Upload</span>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.flowObject = {};

$scope.uploadFiles = function () {
    $scope.files = $scope.flowObject.flow.files;

    // some logic

    myService.uploadFilesSomewhere($scope.files).then(function (response) {
        // some other logic
    });
};

$scope.fileAdded = function (file) {
    // some logic
};
```

Comment: I would like to do it myself than some plugin or anyone else's code. Let me know the  bottlenecks in the present code.